# build where clause to verify only once first clause is met

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I have following sql select:

```
select ...
from table1 a, table2 b
where 
a.column = 'ABC' and
a.column2 = b.column2
```

I would like to only check if `a.column2 = b.column2` when `a.column = 'ABC'`.
How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: exactly as you did it. `and` requires that the values on both sides be true.

Comment: What should happen when `a.column <> 'ABC'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure from your question tag if you're trying to figure out how to do this with a JOIN specifically (as opposed to how you did it with the WHERE clause), but anyway -- a couple of ways:

1) --with WHERE clause

```
select ...
from 
   table1 a

   INNER JOIN table2 b
   ON a.column2 = b.column2

where 
   a.column = 'ABC'
```

2) --WITHOUT WHERE CLAUSE

```
select ...
from 
   table1 a

   INNER JOIN table2 b
   ON a.column2 = b.column2
   AND a.column = 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will check column2 only when column is 'ABC':

```
 select ...
 from table1 a, table2 b
 where 
 (a.column = 'ABC' and
 a.column2 = b.column2) or a.column <> 'ABC'
```

Comment: Please dear downvoter when downvoting add some comment. This where clause does exactly what op wants.